# configure qtnx for a French keyboard layout

Tags: remote-desktop, keyboard-layout, nx

I use the qtnx client to connect to a [NX technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_technology) remote desktop server.

Unfortunately with my French keyboard layout (azerty-like) some keys such as <kbd>AltGr</kbd> do not work. This means I cannot type characters like  `` #{[|`\^@]} `` (located in the top row along with all the digits). Both computers (the one running qtnx, and the one being remotely accessed) run Ubuntu 10.04.

I have tried alternate clients as well:

- opennx returns an error `execvp(/usr/local/bin/nxssh, -nx, -x, -2, -p, 1234, -o, RhostsAuthentication no, -o, PasswordAuthentication no, -o, RSAAuthentication no, -o, RhostsRSAAuthentication no, -o, PubkeyAuthentication yes, -i, /home/bob/.nx/temp/11112/keylog, -B, -E, nx@192.168.0.2) failed with error 2!`
- remmina doesn't work either

How can I make qtnx work with my French keyboard?

Comment: I think this is a bug on qtnx, but is there a work around ? for example, maybe I could write a script so that when I use a particular key, I get the character I'm supposed to ? I wouldn't know how to do that though, and I'm really out of ideas, so please help me. I do need these special characters for my usual work. Thanks.

Comment: have you looked at alternative clients such as [remmina](http://remmina.sourceforge.net/) and [opennx](http://opennx.sourceforge.net/) ?

Comment: Yes I have tried to install them, but I am facing problems for both of them. opennx has been installed but can't connect for a unknown reason, although qtnx does just fine. The error returned is quite cryptic: "execvp(/usr/local/bin/nxssh, -nx, -x, -2, -p, 1234, -o, RhostsAuthentication no, -o, PasswordAuthentication no, -o, RSAAuthentication no, -o, RhostsRSAAuthentication no, -o, PubkeyAuthentication yes, -i, /home/bob/.nx/temp/11112/keylog, -B, -E, nx@192.168.0.2) failed with error 2!" remmina doesn't work either. Can't you help me to work with qtnx instead, which worked just fine ? Thanks.

Comment: If I may add some information, let me just say that the switch to a US keyboard was kindly suggested by Jeremy W, and isn't my idea. Despite the fact that I'm not used to qwerty keyboards, I'm not even sure it would work either, since I think the problem comes from the fact that the 'AltGr' key doesn't work, and qwerty keyboards use that key as well.

Comment: bob, I've removed the reference to a US keyboard (which was in your original question). The bounty that I added to this question was a signal to others to come to your aid. It may be that we don't have many users who work with NX.

Comment: Im facing the same problem now, using QTNX in 12.04 to connect to 10.04 using german keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Which Linux version are you on, and which version of OpenNX have you tried?

You might try installing OpenNX from [svn](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opennx/develop), as I see many recent bug fixes.
Even if it is still not working, this enables you to post the problem on their (very active) forums.

Comment: As I said in the first post, both Linux versions are Ubuntu 10.04. The error I mentioned is actually with the svn version of OpenNX.

Comment: It would have been better had the svn version worked, but on the positive side you can now post a query on their forums and hope for an answer from the developers.